# Logical OR assignment (||=) not working on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, logical-operators

I am trying to use the [Logical OR assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) `||=`. My line of code is as simple as

```js
parish.email ||= parishB.EMAIL
```

Though I am getting

```
/home/joao/dev/geoptapi/prepareServer.js:278
          parish.email ||= parishB.EMAIL
                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '||='
```

My Node version is `v14.17.0`

Comment: The very same docs you have linked to, very clearly state that this is supported from node 15.0 onwards only

Comment: @derpirscher thanks, didn't fetch it, I thought this type of assignment was very old vanilla JS

Comment: You were maybe confusing the *logical* or assignment `||=` with the *bitwise* or assignment `|=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical OR assignment is available on [Node>=15](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment#browser_compatibility)