# Issue with ESLint

Tags: npm, npm-install

I get the following error while trying to run ESLint. Have tried Babel and eslint-parser. Still the same issue.

What exactly is this file? I don't see any particular documentation around this.

```
node_modules/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/dist/rules/informativeDocs.js:95
    descriptionReported ||= tag.description === description && /** @type {import('comment-parser').Spec & {line: import('../iterateJsdoc.js').Integer}} */
```

Content at my package.json

```
"eslint": "^8.43.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^44.2.4",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.3",
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and for my project the solution was to downgrade `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` from `latest` to `^39.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

`eslint-plugin-jsdoc` v44 requires Node 16 or greater: https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc/blob/94cb599304682c901994bf4966453b79bb984613/package.json#L65

The provided code snippet uses the logical OR assignment operator, which is only supported by Node>=15: [Logical OR assignment (||=) not working on NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515305/logical-or-assignment-not-working-on-nodejs)

Which version of NodeJS are you running?